# Unable to run elasticsearch.bat file on windows 11

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I am getting below error while running **elasticsearch.bat** on windows cmd. On my env varaiables **JAVA_HOME** and **JRE_HOME** has already been set.

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19

‪JRE_HOME  = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_361

**Error:**

> D:\Software\ELK\elasticsearch-8.9.1\bin>elasticsearch.bat
>
> warning: ignoring JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19; using ES_JAVA_HOME
> [2023-08-26T09:20:01,863][ERROR][o.e.b.Elasticsearch      ]
> [ADILABDULLAH] fatal exception while booting
> Elasticsearchjava.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <?> at
> index 0: ?C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_361
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:232)
>
> See logs for more details.
>
> ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at
> D:\Software\ELK\elasticsearch-8.9.1\logs\elasticsearch.log
>
> ERROR: Elasticsearch exited unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new environment variable `ES_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19`

Remember to check that by `echo %ES_JAVA_HOME%`